Find and delete all duplicate files by hash
As the title suggests, I'm looking to check a bunch of files on a Linux system, and keep only one of each hash. For the files, the filename is irrelevant, the only important part is the hash itself.
I did find this question which partly answers my question in that it finds all the duplicates.
https://superuser.com/questions/487810/find-all-duplicate-files-by-md5-hash
The above linked question has this as an answer.
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate

Any ideas/suggestions as to add deleting to this answer?
I guess I could use something like php/python to parse the output and split the files into groups by the blank line, then skip the first entry in each group if the file exists, and then delete the rest if they exist.

Don't reinvent the wheel: https://github.com/sahib/rmlint

Oh I should have mentioned I found fdupes and pydupes already, but they didn't seem to allow me to use anything but MD5 which I wasn't wanting to use.

May I ask why you don’t want to use MD5?  Note that fdupes does a byte-by-byte comparison between files too if the MD5 hash matches.  I see no reason whatsoever to not use that.

Take a look to https://github.com/qarmin/czkawka then

Please [edit] the question and explain why the standard tools that use md5sum are not the answer you need. Especially since you are still using md5sum in your example.

I think there are more programs to do that, one of them is called jdupes, but that is based of fdupes so it might (I don't know much about it) also be restricted to md5.

The fdupes tool compares files by their sizes.  For files with the same size, it compares their MD5 hash.  For files with the same MD5 hash, it performs a byte-by-byte comparison.  If the byte-by-byte comparison shows that the files are the same, it gives you the option to keep or delete the duplicate file(s) (if used with the -d or --delete option).
Example run (it only finds empty files in this example, all other files are unique):
$ fdupes -r Mail
Mail/.notmuch/xapian/.restic-exclude
Mail/.timestamp
Mail/.notmuch/xapian/flintlock

Running with -d gives me an interactive menu where I can select which files to preserve.
Set 1 of 1:

  1 [ ] Mail/.notmuch/xapian/.restic-exclude
  2 [ ] Mail/.timestamp
  3 [ ] Mail/.notmuch/xapian/flintlock

( Preserve files [1 - 3, all, help] ):

You may also run the utility in such a way that it automatically deletes all duplicates.  See the manual.
